# WordPress Multisite install in a subfolder won't work with www

Tags: wordpress, redirect, multisite

I have a domain - `www.mydomain.com`
Inside there is a folder with Multisite install - `www.mydomain.com/sites`
Multisite is installed with subfolders.
I have a site, let's say - `www.mydomain.com/sites/mysite`.

Now, when brwosing to `www.mydomain.com/sites` and to `mydomain.com/sites` (without www) - both work.
When browsing to `www.mydomain.com/sites/mysite` - works well too.
But - when browsing to `mydomain.com/sites/mysite` (without the leading www), so it's being redirected to the main site - `www.mydomain.com/sites` instead to the specific mysite.

I figured out it may be related to WP multisite that is main site located in a subfolder, but couldung figure out how to make `mydomain.com/sites/mysite` redirect to `www.mydomain.com/mysite` as expected.

p.s I use fresh install of latest WP

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code in your `.htaccess` file of wordpress installations in subfolders.

for HTTP:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @krishna89, I've already tried this solution but it seems to do wrong redirect.  When this rewrite rule is being added, then browsing to `mydomain.com/sites/mysite` is being redirected to  `www.mydomain.com/mysite`, meaning it removes the base url of the multisite install on /sites. I assume there might be some little tweak needed in this rule to make it work, but I couldn't find it.  Can you please examine again the rewrite rule you've suggested? thanks